Autocorrelation and ARMA model
Consider the market model for security $i$
$$
R_{i,t}=α_i+β_i R_{m,t}+e_i
$$
I'm estimating the parameters of this model (alpha and beta) using OLS. However, the Breusch-Godfrey test indicates the presence of autocorrelation (I'm using 20 lags for about 1200 observations). How do I proceed with the ARMA model? I can not understand the interpretation and especially how it corrects the OLS estimates. How do I obtain the new parameters of the market model with the ARMA correction?
python:
df=pd.read_excel("myfile.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
X = df["index"].pct_change()*100
Y = df["stock"].pct_change()*100
X = X.dropna()
X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
Y = Y.dropna()

# OLS
model_ols = sm.OLS(Y, X1).fit()
residuals_ols = model_ols.resid

lags= int(input("Lags Breush-Godfrey test"))
bg_test = acorr_breusch_godfrey(model_ols, nlags=lags)
print("Breush-Godfrey (H0: no autocorrelation):")
print("Test statistic:", bg_test[0])
print("p-value:", bg_test[1])

if bg_test[1] < 0.05:
    model_arma = ARIMA(residuals_ols, order=(1, 0, 1))
    results_arma = model_arma.fit()
    print(results_arma.summary())

The output:
                  coef        std err     z         P>|z|[0.025      0.975]
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const      -1.626e-05      0.054     -0.000      1.000      -0.105       0.105
    ar.L1         -0.0557      0.170     -0.327      0.743      -0.389       0.278
    ma.L1          0.1532      0.174      0.883      0.377      -0.187       0.493
    sigma2         2.9205      0.061     47.989      0.000       2.801       3.040
    ==============================================================================

This is an example. What are ar.L1 and ma.L1 and why are not significant? What is sigma2?

Can you paste your code and its output, not just the output? Could you paste it as text, not picture? Thank you. I will not focus on whether you should go for ARMA errors or not, but since you do, function arima with argument xreg set to Rm should work.

Did it. Thank you

I think you want to modify model_arma = ARIMA(residuals_ols, order=(1, 0, 1)) by incorporating an external regressor. At least in R that would be the case. Not sure how exactly ARIMA works in Python (if that is Python).

If you are interested in the model parameters using OLS, then the parameters will be unbaised if the error terms are exogenous. If these are exogeneous and you are interested in hypothesis testing and when the error terms are serially correlated/hetroskedastic, then you could correct the estimated scales for the parameters using HAC options in the .fit().

@Math-fun, HAC is an alternative, but regression with ARMA errors as done by Mattia may be better; see Diebold's blog posts "The HAC Emperor has no Clothes" (parts 1 to 3) here. He has recently published a paper on that (with coauthors), too.

@RichardHardy I agree that in general parametric approaches "could" be preferred. I am no fan of HAC scale estimation either and could well relate to scale-invariant "hypothesis testing".  I though understood the question by OP more in the direction of using OLS and if exogeneity holds and interest does not lie on testing, then why care about the standard errors? Thanks for the nice post/link :-)
